# difficult , classical?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ two matrix in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$
 such that $AB=BA$
suppose that all eigenvalues of $B$ are distincts 
1) show that every eigenvector of $B$ is an eigenvector of $A$
2)show that it exist a polynomial $P$ which coefficient are in $C$ such that $deg(P) < n$ and $A=P(B)$

Comment: What have you tried so far? The first part seems straightforward...you say "suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $c$" and then see what $AB = BA$ tells you. You have to consider the possibility that $v$ is not in the image of $A$, but aside from that...

Comment: the first question is easy, I need a hint for the second one :)

Comment: I see...and you couldn't bother to mention that to save us some time? Hmmm. You also haven't answered my real question: what  have you tried so far?  While you're at it, what theorems do you know that might be relevant?

Comment: I tried to use the division of the caracteristic polynomial of A by the polinomial caracteristic of B to have a polynomial of degree less than n and use cayley hamilton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v\ne0$ and $Bv=\lambda v$, then
$$
\lambda(Av)=ABv=B(Av)
$$

> If $Av=0$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

> If $Av\ne0$, prove that $Av=\mu v$, for some $\mu$, and so $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A$.

> Prove there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that both $S^{-1}BS$ and $S^{-1}AS$ are both diagonal.

> If $P$ is a polynomial, then $P(S^{-1}BS)=S^{-1}P(B)S$. Thus $P(B)=A$ if and only if $P(S^{-1}BS)=S^{-1}AS$.

Hence it is not restrictive to assume both $A$ and $B$ to be diagonal. Suppose $B=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$; if $P$ is a polynomial, then
$$
P(B)=\operatorname{diag}(P(\lambda_1),\dots,P(\lambda_n))
$$
If $A=\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$, the problem is reduced to find a polynomial $P$ of degree less than $n$ with
$$
P(\lambda_i)=\mu_i,\quad i=1,2,\dots,n
$$

> Write $P=a_0+a_1X+\dots+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}$ and solve the resulting linear system. Why is it solvable?

Comment: The question requires $\deg P<n$, this can be achieved by Cayley-Hamilton's theorem.

Comment: @i707107 I had a typo, the degree is at most $n-1$. I'm not sure you can do it with Cayley-Hamilton. Anyway, this is a well-known interpolation problem.

Comment: I meant that even if you have $\deg P=n$, we can reduce $B^n$ by $b_{n-1}B^{n-1} + \cdots + b_0 I$ by Cayley-Hamilton. After all, reading your solution carefully, it is not needed anyway.

Comment: you implicitely used that A is diagonalisable , I don't agree maybe you should clarify

Comment: It is true that $A$ is diagonalizable, because it is assumed that $AB=BA$ and $B$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @jhon96 An $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $M$. Since $B$ is diagonalizable (why?), also $A$ is, using the same basis.

Comment: B is not necesserally diagonalisable

Comment: @jhon96 Yes, it is: it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, by assumption.

Comment: oh i'm sorry , I guess i'm dumb thanks mate , and what did you do for the first question

Comment: @jhon96 The eigenspaces for $B$ all have dimension one.

Comment: exactly , so the first one seems more complicated :) thanks for help :)